# Start-Job Problems

Tags: powershell-2.0

Why this code not works ?

```
function teste 
{
    begin
    {
        function lala {
            while ($true) {
                "JJJJ" | Out-File c:\Testes\teste.txt -Append
            }
        }
    }
    process {
        Start-Job -ScriptBlock {lala}      
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please try to improve your formatting in the future? I cleaned this one up for you, but it'd be nice if I didn't have to do it.

Comment: Sure..actually I tried to do this the first time. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is scoping. When Start-Job runs your script block, it runs it in a different context -- one where "lala" is not defined. However, if you were to rephrase your code like so:

```
function Run-As-Background-Job 
{
    begin
    {
        $appendToFile = {
            while ($true) {
                "JJJJ" | Out-File c:\Testes\teste.txt -Append
            }
        }
    }
    process {
        Start-Job -ScriptBlock $appendToFile
    }
}
```

the background job wouldn't try to invoke a name that isn't defined -- instead, the entire script block would be passed to it and things should work.

Note, that I recommend you test **without the while loop** like I did, because that's going to fill up your disk rather quickly.

Also, please aim for more meaningful function and variable names when posting code. :-)

Comment: You are correct, I was doing my tests and forget to Change the names. Sorry.
But still not works :(

Comment: Are you sure? my version looks like this now:

    function Run-As-Background-Job 
    {
        begin
        {
            $appendToFile = {
                    [System.DateTime]::Now | Out-File c:\users\lauri\test.txt -Append
            }
        }
        process {
            Start-Job -ScriptBlock $appendToFile
        }
    }

and that produces "test.txt" with the appropriate content, so maybe there's something else wrong in your code.

Comment: I am copying your code :). tried new session and reload my IDE...not works :(

Comment: Try this: first type `$job = Run-As-Background-Job`, then wait for a while and type `Receive-Job $job` and see what it outputs. [Edit] An even better way: `Run-As-Background-Job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job`.

Comment: Show this error : The term 'PipelineBreakpointerE4078E3092DF4dd9A469F3DC0CBB505C' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or o perable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (PipelineBreakpo...469F3DC0CBB505C:String) [], CommandNotFoundException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Trying whith Run-As-Background-Job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job

Comment: Works, had to put c:\Testes\teste.txt  in quotes "c:\Testes\teste.txt "
Thanks for you help . I will continue with my tests :)

Comment: Disk fillup speed should be modest with repeated invocations of Out-File; Writing a 100 MiB file already takes ages from PowerShell so that won't do anything bad in quite some time.

Comment: I also made the mistaken assumption that the interval would be milliseconds instead of seconds. :-)